# Can I be romantic with my fiancée for her emotional well being?

Tags: nikah, men-women, non-mahram

Assalamu-Alaikum.
I am in a difficult situation and confused. 2 years ago I started dating a Christian girl, however a couple months back I started cleaning my heart and reconnected with Islam and start a fresh halal life. I left all the bad I was doing (weed, porn, music, etc.) and made sincere tawbah multiple times, may Allah accept it.

However me and my girlfriend have been in deep love. I told her I'm becoming a better Muslim and we stopped seeing each other or being romantic and instead I began teaching her about Islam. I wanted to fix the situation and make my life halal but not give her up so I told my parents about her, she was prepared to convert to Islam and we tried to get the nikkah done so we can be with each other. Nevertheless, her mom opposed and said she's too young and this would destroy her family. During that period where I stopped seeing her she became very depressed and lonely (she's is pretty emotional) so I tried emotionally consoling her that saying "we'll get the nikkah done soon, its gonna be okay". But now we can't get the nikkah done for I don't know how long which would emotionally destroy her, understandably as she can't be with the love of her life. Leaving her is not an optional for that would devastate me and her and tear my heart apart.

Nikkah is also not an option for some time. And not being with her for what seems 4-5 years would emotionally destroy her. I am confused on what to do and have asked Allah for guidance, inshallah I can get some here. Currently all I can think of is asking her what the bare minimum is (such as holding hands or saying "I love you") we can do with each other so that she will be okay during this waiting period (I realize there will be sin on my end but I cannot bare putting her through 4-5 years of misery)

Comment: What do you mean by being romantic?As is this question hardly looks like an answerable question within the scope of our site and model. In Islam there are clear limitations on the relationship and interaction between two non-married individuals that are non-mahrams and even for fiancées. I don't know if you are aware of that.

Answer (score -2):

As long as there is no zina its okey, so depending on what you mean by romantic, if you mean talking to her and telling her that you love no problems there.

But if you mean kissing and sexually then no its not allowed